# frame_benchmarking convert Vec to BoundedVec

Tags: benchmark, custom-types, boundedvec

I am unable to get benchmarks to work after changing an extrinsic argument from `Vec<u8>` to a custom type which is a BoundedVec defined in the pallet pallets config.

1. Can someone provide me with more insights into why the BoundedVec is acting differently in the benchmark-runtime.
2. As well as an implementation that converts a string into a valid BoundedVec type, I don't really want to define my extrinsic argument to be Vec, then convert them in the runtime just to satisfy the benchmarks.

Example:

```rust
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
#...

type Bytes: Parameter
 + Member
 + MaybeSerializeDeserialize
 + MaxEncodedLen
 + Into<Vec<u8>>;

# ...
}

# ...
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config<I>, I: 'static> Pallet<T, I> {

  #[pallet::call_index(0)]
  #[pallet::weight(0)]
  fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, bytes: T::Bytes) {
    # Note: T::Bytes used to be bytes: Vec<u8>
    # ...
  }
}
```

The runtime and tests are working correctly, however, when it comes to creating a BoundedVec in the runtime-benchmarks I'm struggling to construct the type required for calling the extrinsic in the benchmarks.

Example of how I am successfully calling the extrinsic from the tests using this conversion from string to the custom BoundedVec type.

```rust
# mock.rs
parameter_types! {
    pub const MaxSize: u32 = 128;
}

pub type Bytes = BoundedVec<u8, MaxSize>;

impl pallet::Config for Test {
  # ...
  type Bytes = Bytes;
}
```

```rust
# test.rs
#[test]
fn it_does_something() {
new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
  let bytes: Bytes = "hello world!"
    .as_bytes()
    .to_vec()
    .try_into()
    .unwrap()
  
  assert_ok!(Pallet::do_something(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), bytes);
  }
}
```

I cannot follow the same approach to creating my BoundedVec as I do in the tests/mock files as I get the following error. `the trait From<frame_benchmarking::Vec<u8>> is not implemented for <T as pallet::Config>::Bytes`

Adding additional traits to the Bytes type `+ TryFrom<Vec<u8>>` results in other additional errors.

```
"hello world!".as_bytes().to_vec().try_into().unwrap()
                                              ^^^^^^ `<<T as pallet::Config>::Bytes as TryFrom<frame_benchmarking::Vec<u8>>>::Error` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `core::fmt::Debug`

adding the suggested where just unravels additional errors so it doesn't seem like the correct approach.
```

```rust
#![cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]

use super::*;

use crate::Pallet;
use frame_benchmarking::{benchmarks, whitelisted_caller};
use frame_system::RawOrigin;


# The function I would like to work. previously It was just returning a Vec<u8>.
fn bytes<T: Config>() -> T::Bytes {
    "hello world!".as_bytes().to_vec().try_into().unwrap()
}

benchmarks! {
    do_something_benchmark {
        let caller: T::AccountId = whitelisted_caller();
    }: do_something(RawOrigin::Signed(caller.clone()), bytes::<T>())
     verify {
        assert_eq!(Pallet::<T>::storage().unwrap().len(), 1);
    }

    impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Pallet, crate::mock::new_test_ext(), crate::mock::Test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay after all of that, I managed to figure it out...

Since `frame_benchmarking::Vec<u8>` wasn't working I decided to focus on converting a BoundedVec to the custom type.

1. Firstly I needed to add the Bytes MaxSize into the config so I can refer to it in the From trait.

```
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
#...
type MaxSize: Get<u32>;

type Bytes: Parameter
 + Member
 + MaybeSerializeDeserialize
 + MaxEncodedLen
 + Into<Vec<u8>>
 + From<BoundedVec<u8, Self::MaxSize>>; 
# ...
}
```

2. Update the runtimes to pass in the additonal type.

```rust
impl pallet::Config for Test {
  # ...
  type MaxSize = MaxSize;
  type Bytes = Bytes;
}
```

3. update the benchmark code

```rust
#![cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]

use super::*;

use crate::Pallet;
use frame_benchmarking::{benchmarks, whitelisted_caller};
use frame_system::RawOrigin;


benchmarks! {
    do_something_benchmark {
        let caller: T::AccountId = whitelisted_caller();

        // Use the BoundedVec TryFrom<Vec> trait
        let bv_bytes: BoundedVec::<u8, T::MaxSize> = "hello world!".as_bytes().to_vec().try_into().unwrap(); 

        // Use the newly defined From<BoundedVec<u8, Self::MaxSize>> trait
        let bytes = T::Bytes::from(bv_bytes);
    }: do_something(RawOrigin::Signed(caller.clone()), bytes)
     verify {
        assert_eq!(Pallet::<T>::storage().unwrap().len(), 1);
    }

    impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Pallet, crate::mock::new_test_ext(), crate::mock::Test);
}
```

I hope this helps someone else who runs into a similar issue in the future!