# How to use bounded_vec macro in benchmarking.rs

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, benchmarking

I was using substrate-node-template, and created some benchmarking functions.

I was able to use bounded_vec macro in tests.rs but, can't able to use it in the benchmarking.rs file

my code

```
#![cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
use super::*;

#[allow(unused)]
use crate::Pallet as Template;
use frame_benchmarking::v2::*;
use frame_support::bounded_vec;
use frame_system::RawOrigin;

#[benchmarks]
mod benchmarks {
    use super::*;

    #[benchmark]
    fn store() {
        let caller: T::AccountId = whitelisted_caller();
        #[extrinsic_call]
        store(
            RawOrigin::Signed(caller),
            b"1".to_vec().try_into().unwrap(),
            b"1".to_vec().try_into().unwrap(),
            b"1".to_vec().try_into().unwrap(),
            bounded_vec![Types{ key: b"1".to_vec().try_into().unwrap(), is_accepted: false }],
        );
    }
    impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Template, crate::mock::new_test_ext(), crate::mock::Test);
}
```

it was working fine when trying to compile `cargo t -p pallet-template -F runtime-benchmarks`

but, it was throwing errors while trying to compile with
`cargo t -p node-template-runtime -F runtime-benchmarks`

error

```
error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `bounded_vec`
   --> /mnt/c/Users/pavan/PROJECTS/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/benchmarking.rs:24:4
    |
 24 |             bounded_vec![Types{ key: b"1".to_vec().try_into().unwrap(), is_accepted: false }],
```

Comment: Try importing it like this: use sp_runtime::bounded_vec;

Comment: I have tried using it but again triggers another error

`error[E0432]: unresolved import `sp_runtime``
 `--> pallets/template/src/benchmarking.rs:9:5`
  `|`
`9 | use sp_runtime::bounded_vec;`
  `|     ^^^^^^^^^^ help: a similar path exists: `frame_support::sp_runtime``
`

Comment: @AlexBean can you pls help me out

Answer (score 2):

The `bounded_vec` macro is only available in `std` context - and therefore not in benchmarks.
You can replace it with `vec![ ... ].try_into().unwrap()`.
It was done this way since it hides an `unwrap`, which could cause a panic in your runtime code. So it is hidden behind the `std` feature.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the bounded_vec import is not working, see an [example in the Substrate repo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/democracy/src/migrations/v1.rs#L162).

However I am not sure you are doing the conversion to bounded_vec propertly anyway as you can't just do a cast from a Vec into a BoundedVec.

See this way of doing it: [How to create a bounded vec from a normal vec?](https://How%20to%20create%20a%20bounded%20vec%20from%20a%20normal%20vec?). In your case it will look something like that:

```rs
use frame_support::BoundedVec;

let your_bounded_vec = BoundedVec::<u8, ConstU32<5>>::try_from(your_unbounded_vec);
```

See another example in this previous StackExchange answer: [frame_benchmarking convert Vec to BoundedVec](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7320/frame-benchmarking-convert-vec-to-boundedvec)